# How to remove utc offset in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
col = pd.to_datetime(arg=col, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='raise')
```

It takes col with format of `2020-04-20T03:18:07.000+0000` and convert it to the proper form.

The problem is that I see `2020-04-20 03:18:07+00:00` I don't need the `+00:00` I don't have offset from UTC. all dates and times are UTC. How can I edit the format to remove this?

Comment: can't you just do `pd.to_datetime(col)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yeah apparently it's the same.. but still give me the offset from UTC which I don't want to have

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove the part after `+`:

```
pd.to_datetime(s.str.extract('([^+]*)')[0], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Output:

```
0   2020-04-20 03:18:07
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thx for your suggestion. But I solved it by doing:
`col = pd.to_datetime(arg=col, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='raise').dt.tz_localize(None)`